# Vim settings to detect includes in D source

Tags: include, d, vim

I am trying to add some support for D programming language to my vim config. For autocompletion I need to detect packages that are included. This is not exactly hard to do in simple case:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.conv;
```

My config:

```
set include=^\\s*import
set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\\.','/','g')
```

Works great.

However, imports can have more complicated format, for example:

```
package import std.container, std.stdio = io, std.conv;
```

I was not able to find a simple way to parse this with `include` and `includeexpr`.

Also there is a second problem: `import` can have different access modifiers, like `public` and `private`. VIM scans included files recursively, `import` statements from included files are parsed too. But I need to distinguish between the file I am working with now and files which are scanned automatically: in current file all imports should be detected, but in other files only `public import` statements should add more files to the search.

Thanks for help.

**Update**

It's a shame if this can not be done without full parsers. Essentially, I only need two things:

- ability to return an array from `includeexpr` instead of one file name
- ability to distinguish between includes in current and other files

Comment: just split on `,` in the simple case

Comment: But can `includeexpr` return multiple file names to include from single string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think only way to do it reliably is to use complete parser and semantic analyzer. D Completion Daemon (https://github.com/Hackerpilot/DCD/tree/master/editors/vim ) has vim plugin and is not very resource-hungry.

Comment: It's not very resource hungry as in CPU usage, but it does eat a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Vim's include mechanism and `'includeexpr'` are heavily influenced by the C programming language and **only work for single files**. You cannot return a list of filenames, so it won't be possible to support D's complex include mechanism with Vim. Use an IDE that is fully tailored to support the programming language, not a general-purpose text editor.